# angular - assigning from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Angular directive that behaves like ng-include, just with tabs.
So it has a hierarchical scope (`scope: true`).

To get and set parent scope's variable value I use $parse:

`var modelFn = $parse(attrs.ngModel);`

getting works fine like this `var value = modelFn(scope)` even `scope.$eval(attrs.ngModel)`,
but assigning doesn't change the value on the parent scope, it actually creates a variable on the current scope:

`modelFn.assign(scope, { ... });`

This is frustrating, any help?
Thanks in advance!

Update:
Here's an example

HTML:

`<myDirective ng-model="myData"></myDirective>`

Directive:

```
{
replace: false,
scope: true,
template: '<button ng-click="changeData()"></button><div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>'
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
var modelFn = $parse(attrs.ngModel);
var value = modelFn(scope);
scope.templateUrl = data.replace('a', 'b');
scope.changeData = function(){


// Problem is here, assignment is on the current scope and not parent ( or parent's parent and etc..)
modelFn.assign(scope, {name: 'new Value'});
}
}
}
```

Comment: why can't you just use `scope.$parent`?  why the `$parse`?

Comment: You should show more code to explain what you are trying to do. It's not clear to me why and how you use `ngModel`

Comment: It's not always the direct parent..
I can't show more, boss doesn't allow, anyway that's explains the problem

Comment: @YuvalSaraf, you don't need to show exact code - in fact, please don't. You should create an illustrative example

Comment: Updated the question with an example

Answer (score 0):

In javascript object have prototype.

When you specify `scope: true` you told the directive to have a scope prototypically inherited from the parent scope.

That means that you get to have a special link to the parent scope (the prototype), where you can access all is values and objects, and all is methods, until... you try to write stuff for those values, objects and methods.

You can see prototype has fallback, when there is no value/object/method on your object, it will try to look at is prototype.
But when you want to set a value/object/method, you'r actually setting it on your object not is prototype, and so your parent scope values/objects/methods nether change.

A bit of code to illustrate :

https://gist.github.com/bcharp/712d6d9bfaf55b3c5d81

An interesting fact to know is that if you change one of the value of an object access through the prototype, it will be change in the prototype object.

So for your current trouble, you can simply change your direct access value say `$scope.title = "My title";` by `$scope.properties = {title:'My title'};` and access it through `$scope.properties.title` when you change it inside your object (directive inherited scope), it will be change in his prototype (parent scope).

I hope it's clear.

Comment: So that's means if anyone wants to use my directive he can't just put the variable on the scope directly like this `$scope.myData` (and in the html put "ng-model='myData'"), he needs to put in in a object like this: `$scope.vm.myData` ("ng-model='vm.myData'").

I wanted to avoid such a weird requirement from the developer...

Comment: Well in that case use isolated scope, not inherited one, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just pass the variable to the directive using two-way binding? The following will bind myParam so that when you change it in the directive it will also change on the calling scope:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      myParam: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    controlle: MyCtrl

... etc...

};
})
```

HTML:

```
<my-directive my-param = "foo"><my-directive/>
```

Comment: That's creates an isolated scope in angular.. no good for ng-include because expressions will not know anything from parent's scopes